# JSON.net Parsing through data

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all i am trying to loop through a json response with the following:

```
Dim url As String = "https://www.[site here].com/api/v1/messages.json?access_token=" & yAPI.userToken
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd)

reader.Close()
response.Close()

Dim mtemp As String = DirectCast(o("messages")(0)("body")("rich").ToString(), String)
```

I can get the data just fine for **mtemp** but it only gets the first set instead of looping thru all the rest of the json resonse.

A sample of the response is:

```
{
   json data here...
},
"threaded_extended": {},
  "messages": [
    {
      "network_id": [edited here],
      "chat_client_sequence": null,
      "privacy": "public",
      "body": {
        "urls": [
          "[edited here]"
        ],
        "rich": "[edited here]",
        "plain": "[edited here]",
        "parsed": "[edited here]"
      },
      "sender_id": [edited here],
      "content_excerpt": "[edited here]",
      "client_url": "[edited here]",
      "client_type": "Web",
      "web_url": "[edited here]",
      "created_at": "2013/08/26 19:31:50 +0000",
      "language": null,
      etc etc...................
    },
    {
      "network_id": [edited here],
      "chat_client_sequence": null,
      "privacy": "public",
      "body": {
        "rich": "[edited here]",
        "plain": "[edited here]",
        "parsed": "[edited here]"
      },
      "sender_id": [edited here],
      "content_excerpt": "[edited here]",
      "client_url": "[edited here]",
      "web_url": "[edited here]",
      "client_type": "Web",
      "created_at": "2013/08/26 19:25:00 +0000",
      "language": null,
      etc etc....
    },
```

How can i continue to loop until it reaches the last instant that i am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`o("messages")` is a `JArray`, so you can enumerate it.  In your code, you're only asking for the first item.  You need a looping construct if you want to loop.

```
For Each msg As JObject In o("messages")
    ' Do something with each msg
    Debug.WriteLine(msg("body")("rich").ToString())
Next
```